# In SwiftUI can I set a locale in Preview for currency etc. but keep generic format for text fields eg Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "GBP"

Tags: swiftui, locale, currency, preview

Xcode version 15.0 set to iOS 15.0
As the title says my App uses Text(someAmount, format: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "GBP") to display an amount of currency the symbol of which should change for each users locale. However in preview I get $ and cannot find a way to change to specific locales for preview only.

I have found some example code which I had to modify slightly to make it run but this changes the non-preview code and is a fixed amount.

```
// App.swift file

import SwiftUI

@main
struct Locale_TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var someCurrency = Currency()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(currency: someCurrency)
        }
    }
}
```

```
// ContentView code.

import SwiftUI

class Currency: ObservableObject {
    let currencyValue: Double = 123.45
    
    func getFormattedCurrency(for locale: Locale) -> String{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = locale
        let formatterCurrency =  formatter.string(for: self.currencyValue) ?? "?"
        return formatterCurrency
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    let currency: Currency
    var body: some View {
        Text(currency.getFormattedCurrency(for: locale)) // Prints £123.45 for en_GB
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(currency: Currency())
            .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "en_GB"))
            
    }
}
```

If I only add the .environment(.locale, .init(identifier: "en_GB")) line to ContentView() in Preview all that happens is $ changes to US$.

Is it possible to set the preview to a specific locale leaving the 'normal' code as is?

Comment: I don't think that is possible inside the preview, what you could do is set your simulator device to UK region in the preview device settings (like you would with a normal iPhone)

Comment: I didn't think of that thanks. It did what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    let currencyValue = 123.45

    var body: some View {
        Text(currencyValue, format: .currency(code: locale.currency?.identifier ?? "USD")
    }
}
```

FYI `@StateObject` is for async Combine pipelines, you probably don't need that.

Comment: Ok thank you. At that point I was just trying to get something the compiler was happy to compile. I can do what I wanted through the settings in the simulator.